# Full path to an awk script from within the script itself

Tags: macos, awk, path

I have an AWK script, i.e., an ascii file executable in linux in which the first line is:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
```

I execute myscript like this, if I'm in the same directory:

```
> ./myscript  afile
```

Or like this, if I'm in a different directory:

```
> pwd
/some_weird_path
> /full_path/myscript   afile
```

How can I have access to "/full_path/" from within the AWK script itself? I've tried the following without success:

```
ARGV[0]  => /usr/bin/awk
ARGV[1]  => afile
ENVIRON["PWD"] => some_weird_path
```

Ideas?

Comment: `ENVIRON["PWD"]` will only list the path from where you launched the script. I don't think you can get what you need without doing some clever calls to OS utilities captured by a `getline var`. Or someone with a better memory will post a `duplicate-question` response (if you're lucky ;-) ). Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

This is ugly but seems to work with gnu awk on linux.

```
BEGIN {
        getline cmdline <("/proc/"PROCINFO["pid"]"/cmdline")
        nf=split(cmdline,fields,/\0/)
        print fields[3]
      }
```

This is even uglier, but it should work on any system with a `ps` implementation, as long as neither the path to awk nor the path to the script include whitespace characters:

```
BEGIN {
        "ps -p "PROCINFO["pid"]" -ocommand=" | getline cmdline
        nf=split(cmdline,fields," ")
        print fields[3]
      }
```

YMMV.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm on a BSD based system without a /proc folder.

Comment: @user1846135: In that case, why did you tag your question as linux? -- Added something which might possibly work.

Comment: Sorry for that, I updated the tags. I'm on OSX which is BSD based. I tried your suggestion but PROCINFO["pid"] does not return anything and hence I get an error: ps: option requires an argument -- p

Comment: Presumably, your awk is not gnu awk. sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to do it. Based on rich's suggestion, which did not work for me on OSX, I regexp'ed on "/usr/bin/awk" to find out which line corresponds to the actual command.

```
BEGIN {
   while ( ( "ps -ocommand=" | getline pslines ) > 0 ) {
      if ( pslines ~ "/usr/bin/awk -f" ) { 
          split(pslines, tmp);
      }
   }
   print tmp[3]
}
```

It should work in any system (not tested)... at least as long as the same user ID is not running another copy of awk at the exact same time.